# How to change colors of two things with UIColorPickerViewController

Tags: swift

I would like to change two colors (icon and background) with UIColorPickerViewController.

Now I can change the color of the icon. But I need to change the color of the background too.

However, I have no idea how to separate the extension part.

Currently, my code is as follows;

```
@IBAction func btnColorPickerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let colorPickerVC = UIColorPickerViewController()
    colorPickerVC.delegate = self
    present(colorPickerVC, animated: true) {
    }
}

@IBAction func bgColorPickerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let colorPickerVC = UIColorPickerViewController()
    colorPickerVC.delegate = self
    present(colorPickerVC, animated: true) {
    }
}
extension ViewController : UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate {
func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    showImage()
    
}

func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    iconColor = viewController.selectedColor

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 2 different `UIColorPickerVieweController` and simply check which is which

```
@IBAction func btnColorPickerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let colorPickerVC = UIColorPickerViewController()
    colorPickerVC.delegate = self
    colorPickerVC.view.tag = 1
    present(colorPickerVC, animated: true) {
    }
}

@IBAction func bgColorPickerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let colorPickerVC = UIColorPickerViewController()
    colorPickerVC.delegate = self
    colorPickerVC.view.tag = 2
    present(colorPickerVC, animated: true) {
    }
}

func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    if(viewController.view.tag == 1) {
        iconColor = viewController.selectedColor
    }
    else if(viewController.view.tag == 2) {
        backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah whoops :) copy pasta haha

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. It says;

Value of type 'UIColorPickerViewController' has no member 'tag'

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a var for the tag and it worked like charm!! thanks again.